# Amplify Auth Exception

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, aws-amplify

I have been trying to configure amplify and it keeps bringing an auth exception.

this is my home page

```
class AppWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AppWidget> createState() => _AppWidgetState();
}

class _AppWidgetState extends State<AppWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _configureAmplify();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appRouter = AppRouter();
    return MultiRepositoryProvider(
      providers: [
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => AuthRepository(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => AuthBloc(context.read<AuthRepository>())
                ..add(const AuthEvent.authCheckRequested())),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp.router(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          routerDelegate: appRouter.delegate(),
          routeInformationParser: appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _configureAmplify() async {
    Amplify.addPlugins([
      AmplifyAuthCognito(),
      AmplifyDataStore(modelProvider: ModelProvider.instance),
      AmplifyAPI(),
      AmplifyStorageS3(),
      AmplifyAnalyticsPinpoint(),
    ]);
    try {
      await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
    } catch (e) {
      //Todo!!: change from log later
      print(
          "Tried to reconfigure Amplify; this can occur when your app restarts on Android.");
    }
  }
}
```

my auth bloc

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  final AuthRepository _authrepository;
  AuthBloc(this._authrepository) : super(const AuthState.initial()) {
    // on<AuthEvent>((_onEvent);
    on<AuthEvent>((event, emit) {
      event.map(
        authCheckRequested: (e) async {
          final userOption = await _authrepository.user;
          emit(userOption.fold(
            () => const AuthState.unauthenticated(),
            (_) => const AuthState.authenticated(),
          ));
        },
        signedOut: (e) async {
          await _authrepository.logOut();
          emit(const AuthState.unauthenticated());
        },
      );
    });
  }
}
```

the error:

```
E/flutter ( 2805): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: AmplifyException(message: Auth plugin has not been added to Amplify, recoverySuggestion: Add Auth plugin to Amplify and call configure before calling Auth related APIs, underlyingException: null)
E/flutter ( 2805): #0      AuthCategory.getCurrentUser
package:amplify_flutter/categories/amplify_auth_category.dart:196
E/flutter ( 2805): #1      AuthRepository.user
package:aws_test/…/infrastructure/auth_repository.dart:10
E/flutter ( 2805): #2      new AuthBloc.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:aws_test/…/auth_bloc/auth_bloc.dart:16
E/flutter ( 2805): #3      new AuthBloc.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:aws_test/…/auth_bloc/auth_bloc.dart:15
E/flutter ( 2805): #4      _$_AuthCheckRequested.map
package:aws_test/…/auth_bloc/auth_bloc.freezed.dart:163
E/flutter ( 2805): #5      new AuthBloc.<anonymous closure>
package:aws_test/…/auth_bloc/auth_bloc.dart:14
```

n.b: ignor the last sentences
He swore he just saw his sushi move.
They were excited to see their first sloth.
Whenever he saw a red flag warning at the beach he grabbed his surfboard.
They throw cabbage that turns your brain into emotional baggage.
There were three sphered rocks congregating in a cubed room.
A quiet house is nice until you are ordered to stay in it for months.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add authentication services to the project. This is done by running `amplify add auth` then in the project directory, going through the console prompts, and then running `amplify push`.
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/flutter/#summary